# formatting printbibliography

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

I want to make a chapter where all the bibliography is printed by using the command `\printbibliography` The problem is that I want to give the same format to all the chapters. But when I try to do so I got a first page with the correct format, then a blank page and finally the bibliography is printed (I attach the file[image])

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={150mm, 227mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{float}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancypagestyle{chapterfirstpage}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \rfoot{\thepage}%
}
%\userpackage{xpatchcmd}

\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{chapterfirstpage}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed}}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % para que ponga 1.1.1.1..
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % para que añadir las secciones en el índice...
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./figuras/}}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibencoding=ascii,style=chem-angew,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epsfig}\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}{\thechapter.}{0.1em}{\Huge}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % figuras
%\usepackage{subfigure} % subfiguras
%\userpackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex
%\usepackage{acronym}%{glossaries}
%\makeglossaries
%\makeglossaries
%\setacronymstyle{long-short}
%\newacronym{DRX}{DRX}{Difracción de Rayos X}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[xindy,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\GlsSetXdyCodePage{duden-utf8}
\usepackage{translator}
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{DRX}{DRX}{Difracción de Rayos X}
\newacronym{EDS}{EDS}{Espectroscopía de Difracción de Rayos X}
\newacronym{E_{C}}{E_{C}}{campo eléctrico coercitivo}
\newacronym{SBR}{SBR}{caucho estireno-butadieno}
\newacronym{DMF}{DMF}{dimetilformamida}
\newacronym{PVDF}{PVDF}{Fluoruro de polivinidileno}
%\makeglossaries
\raggedbottom
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}
    \sffamily
\chapter{Bibliografía}\label{biblio}
%\lhead[\thepage]{CAPÍTULO \thechapter. \rightmark}

\vspace{-50pt}
\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{1pt}
\lhead[ \rightmark]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\cite{park2005micropatterning}
\printbibliography
%\rhead[]{\thechapter. \leftmark}
%\lhead[\thechapter. \rightmark]{}
\markboth{BIBLIOGRAFÍA}{BIBLIOGRAFÍA}
\end{document}
```

The `biblio` file contains the following (I provided an example in order you need to compile this):

```
@article{park2005micropatterning,
    title={Micropatterning of semicrystalline poly (vinylidene fluoride)(PVDF) solutions},
    author={Park, Youn Jung and Kang, Yong Soo and Park, Cheolmin},
    journal={European Polymer Journal},
    volume={41},
    number={5},
    pages={1002--1012},
    year={2005},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Comment: That is quite a maximal minimal example, isn't it? `\printbibliography` creates a chapter for the bibliography, which starts a new page and skips to the next odd page as you have `openright`. To change the style of the bibliography, use the facilities provided by Biblatex.

Comment: Note that `\addbibresource` requires a file extension - `biblio` isn't enough. And you are loading obsolete packages which definitely ought not be used such as `epsfig`. Don't load `colortbl` as well as passing `table` to `xcolor`. Etc. etc. Basically, your preamble badly needs pruning.

Comment: is your intention to have a separate bibliography in each chapter?  if so, then the usual "book" bibliography style isn't what you want; you probably want a style that treats the "in-chapter" bibliographies as sections, not chapters, even if you do want to start each on a new page.  i don't have an answer for the basic `book` class, but i'm sure one exists.

Comment: Isn't [samcarter's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307753/586) what you're after?

Answer (score 7):

`\printbibliography` has an option (`heading=bibnumbered`) which makes the bibliography to be treated like a numbered chapter. So the font etc. is all equal to an ordinary chapter. The only tricky thing was to insert the rule below the chapter title which you manually added after the chapter. So simplify this, I added it to the `titleformat`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={150mm, 227mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibencoding=ascii,style=chem-angew,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}}

\fancypagestyle{chapterfirstpage}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \rfoot{\thepage}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy} 

\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{chapterfirstpage}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed}}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}{\thechapter.}{0.1em}{\Huge}[\vskip-.8\baselineskip\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}]



\begin{document}

\chapter{Normal Chapter}
\cite{park2005micropatterning}

\printbibliography[title={Bibliografía},heading=bibnumbered]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The package `biblatex` offers the macro `\defbibheading` in order to modify the way the heading of a bibliography is built.

So, if you include these two lines just after loading the package `biblatex`, you will get what you want:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
    \markboth{#1}{#1}}
```

With this line you can delete the line where you call `\markboth` in your MWE, at the end.

You can delve even further in this topic reading the section "Bibliography Headings and Environments" of `biblatex` manual (it is the section 3.6.8 of its current version).

Answer (score 3):

Well, the problem with your code is to locate, what is your problem and so which parts of your code are needed to show the problem and which parts are not neccessary.  Because I see that bringing the bibliography into the TOC as numbered chapter I concentrated on this problem.

If you want to correct the header and footer of the first page of each chapter, please ask a new question for that ...

With the following MWE (package `filecontents` only used to have bib file and tex code in one compilable MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{park2005micropatterning,
    title={Micropatterning of semicrystalline poly (vinylidene fluoride)(PVDF) solutions},
    author={Park, Youn Jung and Kang, Yong Soo and Park, Cheolmin},
    journal={European Polymer Journal},
    volume={41},
    number={5},
    pages={1002--1012},
    year={2005},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{book}

\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % para que ponga 1.1.1.1..
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % para que añadir las secciones en el índice...
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex,
  bibencoding=ascii,
  style=chem-angew,
  citestyle=numeric-comp,
  sorting=none,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % added extension .bib ! =================

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\raggedbottom

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext
\cite{park2005micropatterning}
\section{Test1}
\blindtext

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

I got the following result:

[image: result of toc]

[image]

To get this result I used package `blindtext` (do not worry about the resulting warnings) and the possibility of `biblatex` to use option `[heading=bibnumbered]` for command `\printbibliography` to get the bibliography as numbered chapter.  Please see that I added extension `.bib` to line `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` (`\jobname`becomes for example `mwe`, id you have my given MWE in file `mwe.tex`).

Because you used package `babel` you need not to rename the heading for your bibliography, because `babel` can do that for you.